# How to prevent website from closing windows?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

Some websites close windows automatically when I submit something via a form on a webpage. How can I prevent the website from closing the window? Is there a way to instruct a browser to ignore such a close window request from the website?

Comment: Take a look at the [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) event.

Comment: See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window#load_unload_events) about window events